# How to set spinner adapter from firebase query

Tags: android, json, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-spinner

[image]

How can I get a firebase query result into a spinner adapter in android. The image above is a sample structure of my database. I want only those that available to be shown in the spinner, and only the the number is to be shown, so in this example 0954555 will be shown, but in the query i have to get only those whose available is yes. Thank you :)

Comment: On which node you set `ValueEventListner`? Do you use a child event listener?

Comment: I have not done that yet because I do not know the full solution but I guess you mean on "Available" node